# How to access XML values that are not inside a body tag, using BeautifulSoup

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup

Here is a basic XML example that has tags enclosed inside an outer tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
print([tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()])
```

The output is

```
['note', 'to', 'from', 'heading', 'body']
```

But, this second example is more similar to my XML file, where the tags are not enclosed in an outer tag

```
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <to> Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
print([tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()])
```

The output is only

```
['to']
```

How do I access the values of ['to', 'from', 'heading', 'body'] from an xml file like the second example?

This is the data I'm trying to read

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rows>
 3
</rows>
<cols>
 3
</cols>
<dt>
 d
</dt>
<data>
 [[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your XML is not valid, it should have one `root`, so if you can change it, you should get your output.*

**But anyway, you can change the parser to lxml/html to grap the whole document**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print([tag for tag in soup.find('body').findChildren()]) #tags including text
print([tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.find('body').findChildren()]) #only text
```

**Output Tags**

```
[<rows>
 3
</rows>, <cols>
 3
</cols>, <dt>
 d
</dt>, <data>
 [[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
</data>]
```

**Output Texts**

```
['3', '3', 'd', '[[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]\n [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]\n [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]']
```

Comment: I'm downstream from the data source, so for now I need to process the xml file as is.  Thank you for your answer.  I'll only add the following command that accesses the data.

print("rows = ", soup.find('body').find("rows").text.strip())

Comment: How to convert soup.find('body').find("data").text.strip()) to a numpy array of floats

Comment: Try the following or open a new question

`my_array = np.array([tag for tag in soup.find('body').find('rows').text.split()],dtype='float64')
my_array.dtype`